# How make lyx recognize single alphabetic a, b, c ....as mathematical symbols

Tags: math-mode, lyx

I have to describe a mathematical model in words like a story. In this description I explain the variables and parameters, they are mainly alphabetic like d,B, C, R, r and etc. My question is how I make Lyx understand that these letters are mathematical symbols.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  I'm not really experienced with Lyx, but wrapping math expressions between `$...$` should be allowed for in-text presentation.  There are also distinct structures defined for display math; appropriate documentation should be identified on the Lyx website.

Comment: I understand that math-mode will work but it will be very tedious, I have many symbols and I need to activate the math- mode before each symbol. I am searching for a quicker strategy.

Comment: The usual strategies are typing, and clicking a mouse for a menu.  Typing turns out to be faster and more reliable for most people, in my experience.

Comment: @barbara beeton,  I have written my description in Word including all the symbols then pasted it in Lyx. After that I kept on highlighting each symbol and pressing the icon of math-mode. If anyone has another faster method please share it.

Comment: AsI said before, I'm not a Lyx user.  But Lyx does have some support facilities.  Here's a ;ink to a wiki entry that may help: https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/ImportExport#word-read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The keyboard shortcut for inline math is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>, and using that might be quicker than clicking the symbol on the toolbar.

It might also be possible to do it all in one go with advanced find and replace, as you can use math mode in the replace text. So use Edit -> Find & Replace (Advanced), keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. Type e.g. `B` in the search field, and in the replace field hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> and then type `B`. Enable "Whole words", and hit Replace all (or just Replace, if you want to try one at a time).

In the future I'd probably write the text in LyX, and use math mode when needed.

Another method would be to write dollar signs around the variables in Word, e.g. `$B$`, and when you paste the text in LyX, use Edit -> Paste special -> Paste from LaTeX. The LaTeX code for math mode (`$ ... $`) will be interpreted properly.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T. thanks a lot you have provided me with very precious information.